# Windows CMD command: Get subfolder name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I want to make a script which copies some files from different locations.

I have the next folder: C:\Test\FILES\< RANDOM_NAME >\< many_files > . In this folder, I have many files which I need later.

I copy the entire directory < RANDOM_NAME > to my working directory. But later, in my script i need the exact name of < RANDOM_NAME > folder. How can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in (*) do set "folderName=%%a"
```

Under the assumption that the required folder is the only one inside the current directory.

The `for /d` will enumerate the matching (`*`) folders inside the current active directory and the name of the folder is assigned to the `%folderName%` variable.